# Centering equations in cells in longtable

Tags: longtable

I want the displayed equations to be centered in longtable, but it seems that they are shifted to the right a bit.

[image]

Here is the code.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=16.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{ltxtable}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.13\textwidth} | p{0.86\textwidth-2\tabcolsep}}
\hline\hline
\bf LEFT Col. & \bf RIGHT Col.\\
\hline\hline
ABC & \lipsum[2].\\
\hline
abc & \lipsum[2]
\begin{numcases}{u(r)=}
C_1 r + C_2 \log r + C_3 \log (\log r)  \\
 C_4 \log ( \log (\log r))+ C_5 \log (\log ( \log (\log r)))
\end{numcases}
hhu
\begin{align}
C_1 r + C_2 \log r + C_3 \log (\log r)+ C_4 \log ( \log (\log r))+ C_5 \log (\log ( \log (\log r)))
\end{align}
\\
\hline\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Besides, it seems that the table is too big. How to fix this?

Comment: Unrelated to your problem but: From the manual of the package: "`[leqno]` Left-side equation numbering (usually inherited from the `\documentclass`
options). This looks silly with numbered cases!". I agree with that.

Comment: @mickep - The `amsart` documentclass sets the `leqno` option.

Comment: @Mico I know that (and I do not think that is a good idea, but that is another thing). The point in the manual is another if I interpret it correctly (I might be wrong): Adding equation numbers to the left, line by line, to a cases environment looks silly. That is what I agree with.

Comment: @mickep -- Fair enough. (I happen to agree with you!)

Comment: Coming back to the question, I also wonder if you really should use a table here. It could be better to use some kind of description environment or even subsections.  As is, you leave a lot of white space in the left column and the text to the right looks cramped and "prisoned".

Comment: There will be questions (on the left side) and answers (on the right side), hence a table was what I was thinking about. The one I showed was just one QA.

Answer (score 4):

The `amsart` document class would appear to execute some directives that ultimately mess with the equation-builder routines. See [@egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/646022/5001) for a full diagnosis and direct cure. If you don't pursue that solution route, it is necesssary to encase the displayed equations in a `minipage`.

Do also note that the usable width of the second column is not `0.86\textwidth-2\tabcolsep` but, rather, `0.87\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth`.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{amsart}
%\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsthm} % loaded automatically by 'amsart' doc. class
\usepackage[a4paper,width=16.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,cases,calc,lipsum}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{0.13\textwidth} | p{0.87\textwidth-4\tabcolsep-1\arrayrulewidth}}
\hline
\bfseries LEFT Col. & \bfseries RIGHT Col.\\
\hline
abc & \lipsum[2][1-5] \par
\begin{minipage}{\hsize} % <-- new
\begin{numcases}{u(r)=}
C_1 r + C_2 \log r + C_3 \log (\log r)  \\
 C_4 \log ( \log (\log r))+ C_5 \log (\log ( \log (\log r)))
\end{numcases}
hhu
\begin{equation}
C_1 r + C_2 \log r + C_3 \log (\log r)+ C_4 \log ( \log (\log r))
  + C_5 \log (\log ( \log (\log r)))_{\vphantom{a}}
\end{equation}
\end{minipage} % <-- new
\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

Comment: This is what I am looking for. Thanks so much for the explanation and some useful suggestions :).

Comment: The cure might be good, but for the wrong disease. `;-)` Don't blame David when it's not his fault! `:-D`

Comment: @egreg - Good one! I've updated the answer so as not to cast unnecessary shade on David. :-) I've also included a pointer to your -- much more thorough -- diagnosis of the malady and direct cure.

Answer (score 1):

If you try it with `article`, the problem disappears, so it must depend on `amsart` and indeed this is so, because the class executes `\fullwidthdisplay` at every math display and this means

```
\displayindent=0pt \displaywidth=\columnwidth
```

In your context this will produce a larger width than allotted by the `p` column specification. You can solve the issue by telling LaTeX to use `\linewidth` instead.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 11pt, oneside]{amsart}
\usepackage{amsmath,amssymb, amsthm}
\usepackage[a4paper,width=16.5cm,top=1.5cm,bottom=2.cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{longtable,array}
\usepackage{cases}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\modfullwidthdisplay}{%
  \displayindent=0pt
  \displaywidth=\linewidth
}
\newcolumntype{q}[1]{>{\let\fullwidthdisplay\modfullwidthdisplay}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{
  @{}
  p{\dimexpr0.14\textwidth-\tabcolsep-0.5\arrayrulewidth}
  |
  q{\dimexpr0.86\textwidth-\tabcolsep-0.5\arrayrulewidth}
  @{}
}
\hline
\bfseries LEFT Col. & \bfseries RIGHT Col.\\
\hline
ABC & \lipsum[2].\\
\hline
abc & \lipsum[2]
\begin{numcases}{u(r)=}
C_1 r + C_2 \log r + C_3 \log (\log r)  \\
 C_4 \log ( \log (\log r))+ C_5 \log (\log ( \log (\log r)))
\end{numcases}
hhu
\begin{align}
C_1 r + C_2 \log r + C_3 \log (\log r)+ C_4 \log ( \log (\log r))+ C_5 \log (\log ( \log (\log r)))
\end{align}
\\
\hline
\end{longtable}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I changed a little the size specifications so as to cover the entire textwidth.

Please, note that `\bf` has been deprecated for about 30 years.